# How to store ByteBufs inside of a Caffeine LoadingCache without race conditions?

Tags: java, netty, caffeine-cache, netty4

I have a `LoadingCache` that loads a Netty `ByteBuf` from some data. I need to be able to release this data using `release()` once the entry is evicted, however there is a race condition where the entry is evicted before I am able to `retain()` it and the `ByteBuf` returned is invalid.

Here is an example of what I am trying to do - the race occurs when the removal listener is invoked between the get and the retain.

```
LoadingCache<String, ByteBuf> cache = Caffeine.newBuilder()
    .maximumSize(128)
    .evictionListener(
        (RemovalListener<String, ByteBuf>) (string, buf, removalCause) -> {
            buf.release();
        }
    )
    .build(
        key -> {
            ByteBuf byteBuf = null;
            // TODO: Create the ByteBuf from a pool
            return byteBuf;
        }
    );

ByteBuf buffer = cache.get("hello").retain();

// If the entry is evicted between call to get and the retain then a race condition occurs
// That means the reference count drops to 0 before the retain is invoked
```

Is there any way to have Caffeine safely and atomically invoke retain before returning from the get?

Comment: You need to retain in the body of `load`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman `PooledByteBufAllocator` provides a `ByteBuf` with reference count 1 by default so retaining there would cause a memory leak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `asMap().compute` to perform a read/write operation on the entry.

```java
Cache<String, ByteBuf> cache = Caffeine.newBuilder()
    .evictionListener((String string, ByteBuf buf, RemovalCause cause) -> buf.release())
    .maximumSize(128)
    .build();

ByteBuf buffer = cache.asMap().compute(key, (k, buf) -> {
  if (buf == null) {
    buf = // TODO: Create the ByteBuf from a pool
  }
  buf.retain();
  return buf;
});
```

You may also be interested in [pinning](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki/Faq#pinning-entries) where you mark the entry as not evictable by specifying that it consumes zero capacity, so it will be skipped over by a size eviction.

```java
Cache<String, ByteBuf> cache = Caffeine.newBuilder()
    .weigher((String string, ByteBuf buf) -> (buf.refCnt() == 0) ? 1 : 0)
    .maximumWeight(128)
    .build();

public ByteBuf acquire(String key) {
  // above
}
public void release(String key) {
  cache.asMap().compute(key, (k, buf) -> {
    buf.release();
    return buf;
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks - that is a great solution. Is it possible for the buffer to be released during the compute call or will the key be temporarily locked? E.g. compute is invoked, buffer is not null but then released just after the conditional null check.

Comment: The entry will be locked within the map, so other writes will be blocked (to the same hashbin). The compute is atomic, so there is a small penalty compared to lock free reads, but generally should be okay.